# boto3: create_tags on an ec2 instance gives TypeError

Tags: python, boto3

I am trying to add a tag to existing ec2 instances using create_tags.

```
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2', region_name=region)
instances =   ec2.instances.filter(Filters=[{'Name': 'instance-state-name',
                                             'Values': ['running']}])
for instance in instances:
  ec2.create_tags([instance.id], {"TagName": "TagValue"})
```

This is giving me this error:

```
TypeError: create_tags() takes exactly 1 argument (3 given)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, you CANNOT use boto3.resource("ec2") like that.  The boto3.resource is a high level layer that associate with particular resources.  Thus following already return the particular instances resources. The collection document always looks like this

```
# resource will inherit associate instances/services resource.
tag = resource.create_tags(
          DryRun=True|False,
          Tags=[
              {
                  'Key': 'string',
                  'Value': 'string'
              },
          ]
      )
```

So in your code,you JUST reference it directly on the resource collection :

```
for instance in instances:
  instance.create_tags(Tags={'TagName': 'TagValue'})
```

Next, is the tag format, follow [the documentation](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html?highlight=region#EC2.Client.create_tags). You get the filter format correct, but not the  create tag dict

```
response = client.create_tags(
    DryRun=True|False,
    Resources=[
        'string',
    ],
    Tags=[
        {
            'Key': 'string',
            'Value': 'string'
        },
    ]
)
```

On the other hand, boto3.client()are low level client that require an explicit resources ID .

```
import boto3
ec2 = boto3.client("ec2")
reservations =   ec2.describe_instances(
    Filters=[{'Name': 'instance-state-name', 
              'Values': ['running']}])["Reservations"]
mytags = [{
    "Key" : "TagName", 
       "Value" : "TagValue"
    }, 
    {
       "Key" : "APP",
       "Value" : "webapp"
    },
    {
       "Key" : "Team", 
       "Value" : "xteam"
    }]
for reservation in reservations :
    for each_instance in reservation["Instances"]:
        ec2.create_tags(
            Resources = [each_instance["InstanceId"] ],
            Tags= mytags
           )
```

(update)
A reason to use resources is code reuse for universal object, i.e., following wrapper let you create tags for any resources.

```
def make_resource_tag(resource , tags_dictionary):
   response = resource.create_tags(
        Tags = tags_dictionary)
```

Comment: The 4th line `reservations =...` is not valid python.

Comment: Even in it's previous state, this was actually very helpful. I had been using the client patterns for everything. Shortly after I encountered this I switched to using resources because I needed to use Volume waiters that have no client equivalent. It *feels* like resources are the more low level and clients are abstractions.

Comment: @BrunoBronosky  in fact, boto3.resource is recommended if you want to build a pass AWS service across functions/class. boto3.client is handy for debugging out of the box.